# How to visualise cluster

Tags: cluster-computing

What are possible ways to represent(in sense of rendering) a cluster of undirected graph having nodes around 4000. So, one can understand easily a dense distribution of subgraph  and sparse distribution between partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For visualization of complex graph data, we can use gephi software, as it is one of the best option. It is very handy, simple and useful.